# javascript test if URL relative or absolute and not mailto:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tables with buttons/links/email with mailto: and have written a default double click function which on double click of the row will direct the user to the last link in the table.

99% of tables will have the Edit button in the last column.

```
$('table:not(.noDoubleClick) tr td').dblclick(function() {
    var linkEl = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:last-child a');

    if(!linkEl.length){
        return false;
    }

    if (linkEl.attr('href') && linkEl.attr('onclick') === undefined && !linkEl.hasClass("popme")) {
        document.location = linkEl.attr('href');
    } else {
        linkEl.click();
    }
});
```

This works fine until I have a rare table where the last column is a email address with a mailto.

**Q:** How could I check if the href is relative/absolute link only. So that this would exclude mailto: and any other links which are not standard URLs.

I know I could do something like this: `linkEl.attr('href').substring(0, 7) == "mailto:"` to test specifically for mailto but is there a better way of doing this without a load of IFs testing for the different protocols to be excluded.

Update with working solution from @epascarello:

```
$('table:not(.noDoubleClick) tr td').dblclick(function(e) {
    var linkEl = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:last-child a');
    var linkElHref = linkEl.attr('href');

    // Check if has href and http protocol
    if(!linkElHref.length || this.protocol.indexOf("http") !== 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (linkElHref && linkEl.attr('onclick') === undefined && !linkEl.hasClass("popme")) {
        document.location = linkElHref;
    } else {
        linkEl.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think that this is not good enough way to deal with the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by anything else like mailto?  There are a ton of available protocols.  If you only want to handle http(s) or a relative link then that's what you should test for.

Comment: Ok didnt realise they was protocols. "is there a better way of doing this without a load of IFs testing for the different protocols to be excluded". Ie testing if this is only a relative/absolute link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up the protocol using the link's properties.

```
var theProtocol = linkEl.prop("protocol");
var isHttp = linkEl.prop("protocol").indexOf("http") === 0;
```

Comment: I'm curious. Can you explain a bit more? Which protocol would it be if it was a mailto or a relative link?

Comment: So a relative link would default to the http protocol?

Comment: FYI: You can write `this.protocol` instead of `$(this).prop('protocol')`

Comment: @David, `this` is not a link, it is a td element. So no, `this.protocol` will not work in this scenario.

Comment: Why did you use "===" ? I think "==" is enough

Comment: @epascarello I mean in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4waY8/. `linkEl` in the scenario is a jQuery collection of 1 anchor element. You can access `protocol` directly from the DOM element like `linkEl.get(0).protocol`. That was my point.

Comment: @David which does the same thing as prop(). Why mix DOM and jQuery?

Comment: @epascarello again, I was referring to your fiddle. Accessing DOM properties directly is faster than constructing jQuery wrappers. All in all, I was simply pointing out that `protocol` is a native property for anchors with a `href` attribute. Use it or not.

Answer (score 2):

For a textual solution, you could use this regular expression:

```
var x = new RegExp('^([^:/?#]+:)?(//[^/?#]*)?([^?#]*)');
x.match(url);
```

If the second memory position is `undefined` or `http:` or `https:` you're probably dealing with a regular URL.